# Rails 3 + delayed_job: how can I keep track of progress of a task (e.g. progress bar on landing page)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, progress-bar, delayed-job

Delayed_job is finally working for me (using the collectiveidea gem in RoR3) for a couple of tasks. The first is for an admin to upload a zip file of images to a gallery and extract each image to build a photo object belonging to that gallery.  The second is deleting galleries.  These galleries can be pretty big (550 pictures in ~3 minutes), and I'd like to be able to show that a gallery is still being processed or is queued for deletion even if it doesn't show up completely.

Right now, I'm just using the default technique (@gallery.delay.extract_photos and @gallery.delay.destroy).

When the admin clicks the extract link, they are directed to the gallery page (which is empty) with a flash message telling them that it's processing the gallery.  Refreshing the page periodically shows the list of images that have been extracted up to that point.  However, it's not exactly clear when the job finishes, since refreshing once clears the flash message. Basically, I'd like to be able to either show a progress bar that updates every second or so with quantity progress next to it `([======  ] 33/86)` and/or update the gallery to show the images as they are added.

Deleting large galleries can also take a lot of time, so I'd like to keep that as a delayed job, too.  However, the gallery still exists when you go to the landing page after deleting it, so it shows up until after refreshing after it's completely gone.  I'd like to either have a way of marking it as queued for deletion or show a progress bar and have it disappear when it's finished deleting.

I've looked around for RoR3 AJAX help, but everything I seem to find has been for 2.3.8 and is deprecated.  Furthermore, I need to know how to track whether a job is still being performed, and I haven't noticed anything like that on collectiveidea's documentation.  I figured since jobs are stored in a table, maybe I could track it using DelayedJob.thisjob.exists? or something along those lines, but trying DelayedJob.all in the rails console just gave me errors (even while the job was running).

So my question, in summary: how can I track a delayed job and display it's progress in any of these ways in the view? **[edit]** I know I can do active polling on the gallery pages, but I don't want to have that happening all the time - just while the job is being performed (or is scheduled).  Is there a way to test for the existence of a job that's being performed or that is scheduled to be performed? Because I haven't found a way track it in the views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Response ...

> Is there a way to test for the
>   existence of a job that's being
>   performed or that is scheduled to be
>   performed?

You could use

```
Delayed::Job
```

to get the Active Record jobs in queue and their statuses .

```
Delayed::Job.find :all , :conditions=>"locked_at IS NOT NULL"
```

I would recommend you use resque for a fine-grained control over your processes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option of using Nginx and its upload modules? I hope so, because that would improve the performance of your app overall. Check this blog post by Gautam Rege, where he uses Nginx, Rails and Delayed Job for relatively large uploads:

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/10/20/uploading-multiple-files-with-nginx-upload-module-and-upload-progress-bar/

The post doesn't mention if he's using Rails 3, but since Nginx is handling the uploads, there's not a lot of Rails code there and you should be able to adjust it if necessary.

Comment: I'm using Dreamhost, and Nginx is an optional feature if you have a PS account, which I'm unfortunately not able/willing to commit to at this point. I'm not sure this is quite the solution I'm looking for, but it's definitely something I'll be considering at a future stage of the project.